# How to get user roles in camel processor? (Spring security + REST Service + Camel)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, apache-camel, restful-authentication

I use Spring security to protect access to rest service on server. Application use Camel framework to handle request/messages. So when request pass though spring security, then camel transform it to the Exchange class (I'm using CXFRS Component for that), and further processing is prepared by camel processors. Way of processing exchange should depends on user role, but:

How to bring out the user from the exchange?

Comment: Is the REST service and Spring security configuration part of your Camel route or external to it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, CXF Camel component stores the authentication object in a header called `Exchange.AUTHENTICATION`. Look into [Camel-Spring Security integration](http://camel.apache.org/spring-security.html) for more details.

If you need more raw access, check [this link](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/HttpServletRequest-associated-with-CXF-endpoint-td5716897.html). It explains how to get the current `HttpServletRequest` object. From there, you should have access to the session and thus, SecurityContext. Something like:

```
Message cxfMessage = exchange.getIn().getHeader(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_MESSAGE, Message.class); 
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)cxfMessage.get("HTTP.REQUEST");
User currentUser = getCurrentUser(request);

public static User getCurrentUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session != null) {
        SecurityContext securityContext = (SecurityContext) session.getAttribute((HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY));
        if(securityContext != null && securityContext.getAuthentication() != null && securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal() != null &&
            securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal() instanceof User) {
            return (User)securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You might even be able to get it directly from `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`.

Comment: import statements would be nice

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide more detail on how the camel transforms the request to an exchange class. Say your request comes in as a MyRequest class, you should be able to do something like this:
`MyRequest incoming= (MyRequest)exchange.getIn().getBody();`
   `incoming.getUser();`

Comment: I'm not sure how this mapping exacly works- I use CXFRS Component for that.